# How to find out mail enable dns settings?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, email

I have just installed mail enable on my server.

I need help understanding what is the IP of my mail server and where to point my MX records?

Say if my server IP is `81.222.222.222` is this where I point my MX records etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get email working you actually need 2 DNS records.

1. Create an "A" record that gives a name to the mail server and points to the IP. eg: `mail.yourdomain.com. A 81.222.222.222`
2. Create an "MX" record that points to your mail server name. eg:
   `yourdomain.com. MX 10 mail.yourdomain.com.`

The 10 in above example is the priority. If you have multiple records, the lower the number, the higher the priority.

Comment: so to be clear...i have an a record for mydomain.com and then an a record for mail.mydomain.com which both point to the same ip?

Comment: then i point the mx record at mail.mydomain.com?

Comment: A records tell which IP belongs to which name, since you need to point an MX record to a name, you also need to match that name to a IP address. the A record for "yourdomain.com." is not required, however you probably want to point such an address to your http server.